# Função não definida - Uncaught ReferenceError: codeAddress is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, api

Estou rodando um script pra pegar a localização de algumas lojas credenciadas da empresa que trabalho (utilizando a API do Google Maps JS). O código funciona em 2 páginas normalmente, porém na ultima página em que vou implementar essa função, ele está dando esse erro.. O código em JS é esse:

```
<script>








var geocoder = null;
var map = null;
var customerMarker = null;
var gmarkers = [];
var closest = [];

function initialize() {
  // alert("init");
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.730751, -89.940637),    /* 52.6699927, -0.7274620*/
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var coordStr = locations[i][4];
    var coords = coordStr.split(",");
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]));
    bounds.extend(pt);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pt,
      map: map,
      icon: locations[i][5],
      address: locations[i][2],
      title: locations[i][0],
      html: locations[i][0] + "<br>" + locations[i][2]
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })
      (marker, i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}

function codeAddress() {
  var numberOfResults = 25;
  var numberOfDrivingResults = 5;
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      if (customerMarker) customerMarker.setMap(null);
      customerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
      closest = findClosestN(results[0].geometry.location, numberOfResults);
      // get driving distance
      closest = closest.splice(0, numberOfResults);
      calculateDistances(results[0].geometry.location, closest, numberOfDrivingResults);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function findClosestN(pt, numberOfResults) {
  var closest = [];
  /*document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "processing " + gmarkers.length + "<br>";*/
  for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    gmarkers[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pt, gmarkers[i].getPosition());
    /*document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "process " + i + ":" + gmarkers[i].getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + ":" + gmarkers[i].distance.toFixed(2) + "<br>";*/
    gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    closest.push(gmarkers[i]);
  }
  closest.sort(sortByDist);
  return closest;
}

function sortByDist(a, b) {
  return (a.distance - b.distance)
}

function calculateDistances(pt, closest, numberOfResults) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  var request = {
    origins: [pt],
    destinations: [],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
    request.destinations.push(closest[i].getPosition());
  }
  service.getDistanceMatrix(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('side_bar');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

      var results = response.rows[0].elements;
      // save title and address in record for sorting
      for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
        results[i].title = closest[i].title;
        results[i].address = closest[i].address;
        results[i].idx_closestMark = i;
      }
      results.sort(sortByDistDM);
      debugger;
      
      
      
      for (var i = 0; ((i < numberOfResults) && (i < closest.length)); i++) { 
        if (results[i].adress == "R. Indalécio Rezende, 850 - Jardim Primavera"){
          
        outputDiv.innerHTML +=  " <div class='espaco'   style='margin-left:40px; margin-top:10px'> <a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest[" + results[i].idx_closestMark  + shows_cred_pf() + "],\"click\");'>" + results[i].title + '</a><br>' +   results[i].address + "<br>" + results[i].distance.text + ' aproximadamente ' + results[i].duration.text + '<br><hr></div>';
        
     
        closest[i].setMap(map);
        i = numberOfResults;
   
       /* outputDiv.innerHTML +=  " <div class='espaco'   style='margin-left:40px; margin-top:10px'> <a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest[" + results[i].idx_closestMark  + "],\"click\");'>" + results[i].title + '</a><br>' +   results[i].address + "<br>" + results[i].distance.text + ' aproximadamente ' + results[i].duration.text + '<br><hr></div>';
        
  
        closest[i].setMap(map);
        i = numberOfResults;
*/

      }
    }
  });
}

function sortByDistDM(a, b) {
  return (a.distance.value - b.distance.value)
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
// Store Name[0],delivery[1],Address[2],Delivery Zone[3],Coordinates[4] data from FusionTables pizza stores example
var locations = [
  

    
      ["Rio Claro - Rio Pneus", "no", "R. Quatorze, 2180 - Vila Elizabeth (Bnh)", "<coordinates></coordinates>", "-22.403572, -47.573710" , "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
      ["Porto Ferreira - Zanon Centro Automotivo", "no", "R. Indalécio Rezende, 850 - Jardim Primavera", "<coordinates></coordinates>", "-21.858959, -47.488320" , "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
      ["Pirassununga - Bosch Multicenter", "no", "Av. Padre Antônio Vann Ess, 1566 - Rosário", "<coordinates></coordinates>", "-21.998977, -47.448747" , "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
      ["Limeira - TS Pneus Frotas", "no", "R. André Scarpa, 8 - Jardim Sao Pedro", "<coordinates></coordinates>", "-22.578118, -47.387098" , "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
      ["Cordeirópolis - Deluca Auto Center", "no", "R. João Batista Spanhol, 655 - Bombocado", "<coordinates></coordinates>", "-22.496744, -47.450244" , "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
      ["Araras - Casa do Amortecedor", "no", "Av. Loreto, 919 - Jardim das Flores", "<coordinates></coordinates>", "-22.360491, -47.366686" , "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
      ["Campinas - TS Pneus", "no", "Rua Salto Grande, 55 - Jardim do Trevo", "<coordinates></coordinates>", "-22.928338, -47.067516" , "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
   
    
 /*["John Paul's Pizzeria", "no", "1100 El Camino Real, Belmont, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.304268,37.516534,0 -122.300835,37.505096,0 -122.262383,37.481669,0 -122.242813,37.502917,0 -122.244186,37.534232,0 -122.269249,37.550021,0 -122.291222,37.545122,0 -122.302895,37.537499,0 -122.304268,37.516534,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.520436,-122.275978", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png"],
  */ 

  
  
  
  
]; 
</script>
```

O erro é este:
 Uncaught ReferenceError: codeAddress is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (ofertasnovo:380)

e ele é nesta linha:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" onclick="codeAddress();" style="margin-top: 7%; width: 80%; height: 130px; background-color: #FDCB1A;font-size: 150%; color: #0E4090; font-weight: 700; letter-spacing: 2px" >BUSCAR CREDENCIADA MAIS PRÓXIMA</button>
```

Comment: só com isso é difícil saber... o script está incluido na página? viu na ferramenta do navegador se tem algum erro pra carregar o script? coloca o script aqui e veja se acusa erros: http://beautifytools.com/javascript-validator.php

Comment: sim o script está na página, não deu erro pra carregar, o estranho é que nas outras páginas ele funciona perfeitamente, apenas nessa que não (sei que não é o jeito ideal, colocar 2 scripts iguais em 2 paginas diferentes, ao invez de simplesmente chama-lo quando necessario, mas é assim que está feito), e os erros que o site acusou são coisas praticamente inexpressivas, como "Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'."